# Laravel default mail after applying ssl not working

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, smtp

I am not receiving password reset mail after applying SSL on my site.Can anyone pls guide me.Only default laravel mails are not working other mails with Mailer class are working fine.

1.**.env** Mail Setting on godday server

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp  
MAIL_HOST=localhost  
MAIL_PORT=25          
MAIL_USERNAME=        
MAIL_PASSWORD=        
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=

On reset password getting success msg but not receiving mail.I already tried too many solution from stakeoverflow.Pls guide me.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: see the laravel.log and cpanel log. If there is any error regarding mail update your question with error

Comment: ok..I will check it..wait

Comment: @SaadSuri no error found in both the files.

Comment: @Surabhiv try SSL in MAIL_ENCRYPTION of .env

Comment: @path shah on using ssl encryption **Connection could not be established with host localhost [ #0]**

Comment: Most possible port is different for ssl. try 465 or contact godaddy support for port.